# Write the PHP command line log to a file like in Python

Tags: php, logging, command-line, command, command-line-interface

In Python, we can add the `command line` log to a file instead of the `console` using this command:

```
python script.py >> mylogfile.txt
```

How can I do it using PHP? I've tried

```
php script.php >> mylogfile.txt
```

but it doesn't work.

I use Windows 10.

Comment: What doesn't work ? Show us the error and the script you are running (MVCE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It's based on the article *[PHP on the Command Line – Part 1 Article](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-command-line-1-2/)*

I first used `php script.php > mylog.txt` which returns some of the log text to the console, so I thought it's not writing to the log, but it does. I **wanted** `php script.php > mylog.txt 2>&1` which will add any log to the file.

The article says it doesn't work in Windows, but I use Windows 10 and it works.

The error messages are mixed with the normal output as before. But by
piping the output from the script, I can split the errors from the
normal output:

`php outwitherrors.php 2> errors.log`

This time, you’ll only see these messages:

> Opening file foobar.log Job finished

But, if you look into the directory in which you ran the script, a new file called *errors.log* will have been created, containing the error
message. The number 2 is the command line handle used to identify
[standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)). Note that 1 is handle for [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), while 0 is the handle for standard error. Using the `>` symbol from the command line, you can direct output to a particular location.

Although this may not seem very exciting, it’s a very handy tool for
system administration. A simple application, running some script from
cron, would be the following:

```
php outwitherrors.php >> transaction.log 2>> errors.log
```

Using ‘>>‘, I tell the terminal to append new messages to the existing
log (rather than overwrite it). The normal operational messages are
now logged to file *transaction.log*, which I might peruse once a month, just to check that everything’s OK. Meanwhile, any errors that need a quicker response end up in file *errors.log*, which some other cron job might email me on a daily basis (or more frequently) as required.

There’s one difference between the Unix and Windows command lines,
when it comes to piping output, of which you should be aware. On Unix,
you can merge the standard output and standard error streams to a single destination,
for example:

```
php outwitherrors.php > everything.log 2>&1
```

It reroutes standard error to standard output, meaning that both get
written to log file *everything.log*.